# Warning: Illegal string offset 'woo_layout' in

Tags: warnings

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'woo_layout' in
>   /home/lifeguru/public_html/wp-content/themes/canvas/includes/theme-actions.php
>   on line 736

Please help

Comment: You have to show us some code.

Comment: Please add tag, which language, editor..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a bit unclear. Please tell us what you're using (WooCommerce perhaps?), and show us the lines where this error occurs. Also explain _when_ you get this error. WIth this information, we may be able to help you. Use the "edit" link below your post to edit this information into the question. Good luck!